# Sync folders & files from Windows 2003 server to Windows 2012 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, rsync, robocopy

I need to sync several hundred GBs of data from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2012 R2 server.  I originally thought of using Rsync via my Linux box but Googling an answer showed me Robocopy and XXCopy.  Well, XXCopy wants money and the Windows Resource Kit Tools won't install on my 2003 server (corrupted cabinet file error).

Suggestions?

PS I know nothing of cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

Just initiate the robocopy from your 2012 R2 server. You don't need to install anything on 2003.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed to work fine once I got the permissions straightened out and figured out I had to run the terminal as an administrator.

Comment: Additional question: if I want an incremental backup (the 2003 server is going away eventually and I want the 2012 server ready to take over), do I want to mirror or just copy?

Comment: @ClaytonTavernier mirror, /mir, especialy when your source folder is big like in your case

Answer (score 0):

If your domain schema is not much updated, use a DFS, its builtin to sync folder.